# Scroll to top when using pagination in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am loading data card and when I press pagination buttons, the data changes but screen remains in the same place. How do I scroll to top when button is pressed? The application is a SPA so maybe that is causing the issue?

```
const getCoinsData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.get(
        `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=100&page=${activePage}&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d`
      );
      setData(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way you could do it is with a useEffect in the component gets the new data on page change

edit should have updated the dependencies. I am assuming your list is coming in as a variable named `data`. Just add that to the dependency array. You could use your `data` object or your `isSuccess` boolean if you have one.

```js
    useEffect(()=>{
        window.scrollTo({top: 0});
    },[data])
```

Comment: Not working. Maybe due to SPA

Comment: I failed to include the `data` object (or what your list object is called)  in the dependency array

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    getCoinsData();
  }, [activePage]);useEffect(() => {
    getCoinsData();
  }, [activePage]);`

Comment: My useEffect already has a dependancy to reload on each page change, should I add a coma and add data as well?

Comment: It does depend on how your data is setup but yes. Give it a try and let me know. I am curious to know if it works

Comment: Should I add it in the same [] or another []?

Comment: useEffect(()=>{},[variable1, variable2, data, variable3, ...etc])

Comment: This did not work

Comment: Strange. useEffect should be called each time a dependency changes, in your case the data object, which should trigger the code inside to run, in your case, scroll to the top.

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    getCoinsData();
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
  }, [activePage, data]);`

Comment: This my useEffect

Comment: Post more of your code in your initial ask. I am curious what `getCoinsData()` does and where the returned data is stored.

Comment: See thee question please

Comment: So the useEffect, getCoinsData(), [data, setData] = useState() are all in the same exact component? or are they split between two components / files

Answer (score 1):

Since the application is a SPA, the page is likely not reloading when you move to next page. You'll have to manually scroll to the top of the component.

To do that, add a ref to the wrapper of the content that you want to scroll to the top of:

```js
const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

// ... blablabla component stuff

return {
  <div ref={wrapperRef}></div>
}
```

Then just make sure you next page button handler has access to the ref:

```js
const handleNextPageButtonClick = async () => {
  await getNextPage();
  wrapperRef.current.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using window.scrollTo({top: 0}) (as suggested by epicmau5time) worked for me, however, I'd suggest using useMemo rather than useEffect. I'm working on a SPA as well, and using Pagination. So I used useMemo and included the currentPage variable as its dependency.

```
useMemo(() => {
    window.scrollTo({top: 0})
  }, [currentPage])
```